# PowerShell: How to get windows disk layout, e.g. simple or spanned?

Tags: powershell, disk, windows-server

In the `diskmgmt.msc`, I can see the disk layout info as below:

[image]

I am trying to get the same information through PowerShell. None of the usual disk and volume related commands seemed to have the info. Now, I am not sure how true this is but I was told that `list volume` in `disk part` holds this information as below:

[image]

However, `disk part` info is often error-prone to parse programmatically. I was wondering if anybody knows of a better way to do this?

Comment: It might be possible that the *written* status you see in the diskart output or in a graphicla interface is represented by a numerical value you can see in the output of some command line tools or commands. Try `Get-Partition` or one of the classes you get with `Get-CimClass -ClassName *partition*`